# Put checked checkboxes into an array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays, associative-array

TO CLARIFY I'VE GOT THE VALUES OF THE CHECKED CHECKBOXES. I NEED TO ORGANIZE THEM IN AN ARRAY SIMILAR TO THE PHP EXAMPLE GIVEN. THANKS

I'm trying to build an array of checked checkboxes to be sent over AJAX for processing by PHP. Originally I got the selected checkboxes by PHP but I'm having trouble converting this process to Javascript.

There are three different groups of checkboxes ('first', 'second', 'third') and for each of these groups there are 4 different checkboxes that can be checked.

The html of the checkboxes followings the same pattern up to value 4.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="first" class="selection first"  value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="second" class="selection second" value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="third" class="selection third" value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="first" class="selection first"  value="2"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="second" class="selection second" value="2"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="third" class="selection third" value="2"  />
```

and so on....

The PHP code would return an array of the checked checkboxes like such.

```
$selections => array(
['first'] => array(
[0] => 1,
[1] => 3,
[2] => 4),
['second'] => array(
[0] => 2),
['third'] => array(
[0] => 1,
[1] => 4)
);
```

I've been trying and trying to replicate this in JavaScript but I keep getting errors such as `cannot convert undefined to object` and the likes. I loop the available positions to create arrays, then loop all the checkboxes and if checked, I get the value.

`console.log()` prints the position ('first', 'second' or 'third') and the number of the selection (1 - 4). That's all I need, but how do I put this in an array similar to the PHP one?

```
function getSelections() {

var selections = new Array();

$('.position').each(function() {
    selections[$(this).attr('value')] = new Array;
});

$('.selection').each(function() {
    if( $(this).prop('checked') == true ) {
        position = $(this).attr('name');
        selection = $(this).attr('value');

        console.log(position + ' - ' + selection);
    }
});
return selections;
```

}

It's to be sent to a PHP script as JSON and I need to decode it as an array like the PHP one.

Comment: Search jquery checkboxes abd youll find like ten duplicate questions ..

Comment: I'm not asking how to get the selected checkboxes, if you read the question you'll find I've got the values of the selected ones, I'm looking how to put them into an array similar to the php one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing fancy needed.... change to this and view the posted arrays.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="first[]" class="selection first"  value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="second[]" class="selection second" value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="third[]" class="selection third" value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="first[]" class="selection first"  value="2"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="second[]" class="selection second" value="2"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="third[]" class="selection third" value="2"  />
```

Then serialize this as normal to submit via ajax instead.

Comment: thats how I was orignally doing it with PHP, didn't know it would work with JS. I'll try serialize and let you know if it works! thanks alot!

Comment: the values are coming across in ajax now! Thanks for you help!

Comment: Lesson for today... never try to make it more complicated than it needs to be! Try simple things first :)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery [:checked Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) may help